# Automating terminal login with DSA key

Tags: terminal, openssh, ssh-keys, dsa

How would I go about doing this on the terminal?

sftp   then asks me for a password.  how do I include my DSA key so that I do not have to use the password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `sftp` uses SSH protocol for communication, you may generate private/public key pair using [ssh-keygen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ssh-keygen/) (read everything their!). Then read [this HOWTO](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) about how to transfer your key to remote server. If you need more, read more detailed description of [OpenSSH Public Key Authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/).

If you setup your key correctly, and remove SSH server is configured to use key authentication, you will be granted the access without additional password.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh-agent running, holding the key to the site, it will handle authentication for you.